# Retrieving and Displaying data from Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, information-retrieval

I'm currently learning about Java and Firebase. I've been trying to retrieve data from Firebase. I read through many docs and examples from Firebase and other solutions posted on stackoverflow but still couldn't solve it.

I posted a screenshot of the database below. I'm trying to retrieve the "customers" node. For example, I want to retrieve the transaction history of the current user who logged in and display their transaction history such as "Status" and "firstName". However, I'm currently displaying only the user id and not the transaction history. Below is my code. I'm not sure whether I'm doing it correctly and I may not fully understand the codes as I'm learning through online sources. Can anybody help me go through my codes? How do I display the information (Status and firstName)? Thanks!

Edited: I solved it!

Comment: I still didn't get what you want, from your code you are doing good, now whats is the problem?

Comment: @MuhammadFarrukhFaizy I'm trying to display status and firstname but i don't know how to display it. It is displaying the user id instead.

Comment: can you show me the output?

Comment: @MuhammadFarrukhFaizy I have added the screenshot of the output in the post. It has 6 transaction history but instead it shows the the id of the person who logged in. Instead of the id, i want it to show the status and first name instead.

Comment: @MuhammadFarrukhFaizy Hey thanks for the help! I have managed to solve it. :)